# Tengo que hacer 2 veces clic para poder abrir sección

Tags: php, html

Cuando le doy clic en el login para ingresar, tengo dar otra vez clic para que pueda enviarme a la pagina de inicio.

Agrego el código del login del controlador del modulo y la conexión.

```
<form action="inicio" method="post">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="ingUsuario" required>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="ingPassword" required>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        
          
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
              <label for="remember">
                Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
           

          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        

        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <?php

                $login = new ControladorUsarios();
                $login -> ctrIngresoUsuario();

               ?>
               </div>
      </form>
```

Aquí agrego el controlador:

```
<?php

// Ingreso de usuario//

class ControladorUsarios{

    public function ctrIngresoUsuario()
    {

    if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"]))
        {
    
    if (preg_match('/^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) && preg_match('/^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])) {
                
                $tabla = "usuarios";
                $item = "usuario";
                $valor = $_POST["ingUsuario"];

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlmostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

                if ($respuesta["usuario"]==$_POST["ingUsuario"] && $respuesta["password"]==$_POST["ingPassword"]) {
                    // code...
                    
                    $_SESSION['iniciook'] = "ok";

                    echo '<script> window.location ="inicio" <script> ';


                    }
                    else{

                        echo '</br> </br><div class="alert alert-danger">Error en usuario o password </div>';
                    }



            }


        }
}
}
```

Aquí agrego el modelo:

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios{

    public static function MdlmostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor){

$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
$stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> execute();

return $stmt -> fetch();


    }

}
```

Aquí agrego la conexión:

```
<?php

class Conexion{

    public static function conectar(){

        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=posmax","root","");

        $link->exec("set names utf8");

        return $link;

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos dónde haces clic? ¿En el botón que pone **Sign In**? ¿Podrías mirar en el inspector de red si se produce una petición HTTP al pulsar el botón? ¿Tienes código javascript en la página que pudiera interferir con el evento de enviar el formulario o de pulsar en el botón?

Comment: bueno estoy comenzando en esto pero le doy aqui
` <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
           

          </div>` 
Que debo hacer

Comment: Apreta f12, metete a la seccion Network, recarga, haz click al boton, y mira que respuesta obtienes.

Answer (score 0):

ya vi cual era el problema en el controlador en el script window.location no lo cerré, ya lo acomode y si funciona bien gracias.

el error
 `echo '<script> window.location ="inicio" <script> ';`

lo correcto
`echo '<script> window.location ="inicio" </script> ';`

Saludos